# Login/Sign Out working but page not navigating to Dashboard in Flutter/Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, stream-builder

I am writing a login/sign out function for a project. The logic seems to work as I get it logged in vs code terminal but it doesn't navigate to the specified page. I'm using StreamBuilder in a separate auth_verify file that controls the authStateChanges.

This is my auth_verify.dart:

```
class AuthVerify extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthVerify({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print("Logged In");
            return const DashboardScreen();
          } else {
            print("Logged Out");
            return const WelcomeScreen();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the signIn and signOut function:

```
userSignIn() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: usernameController.text.trim(),
        password: passwordController.text.trim(),
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void userSignOut() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
```

I have a login_screen.dart that has the login form where onPressed goes to the userSignIn function.

I have been stuck on this for quite sometime now. I have already tried creating new files with the same content, doesn't work on that too. Changed the auth page to become stateful widget, it still doesn't work. I know I'm doing part of it right because it does log in and out but i need to swipe left and the context.pop triggers and takes me to dashboard when logged in and the welcome screen when logged out. but it doesn't happen on button tap.